# Numeric column with dynamic row format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If I have a MyISAM table with Dynamic as row format, are the numeric columns (int(11), bigint(12)..) dynamic or static columns?

For example, if I have int(11) as the column type but the maximum value for this column is 1234, in this case does this column use only the space required which is int(4) or does it use the space like int(11)?

Comment: The `()` has **NO**  effect on storage requirements. an `int` is an `int`, no matter what, and occupies 4 bytes. The `()` is simply there to tell mysql how many digits should be displayed, `int(1)` will STILL occupy 4 bytes, just as int(11) will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For dynamic row format in MyISAM every column is dynamic: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dynamic-format.html
- int(4) and int(11) both take 4 bytes

> The length just specifies how many characters to display when selecting data with the mysql command line client.

Comment: I read mysql Doc before asking the question but I didn't understand. so what do you mean by "every column is dynamic" ? int can occupy less than 4 bytes ??

Comment: It is more about row format itself. The fact that int is fixed length is not so important, also `If a numeric column has a value of zero, it is marked in the bitmap and not saved to disk`